# Second Order Euler Equation Please explain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have equation of type:
$$
a x^2  y(x)'' + bxy(x)' + cy = d(x)
$$
it is called, in my text book, a second order Euler equation. They say that I need to put $e^t$ instead of $x$ and than $Y(x(t))=y(x)$

After this, they write that it is clear that: 
$$\begin{align}
x\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{dY}{dt}\\ 
(x^2)y'' &= \frac{d^2Y}{dt^2}-\frac{dY}{dt}
\end{align}
$$
Please tell me what are they doing here.

thanks.

Comment: can you tell us the name of the book and the page ? or can you provide the full text?

Comment: Also [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerDifferentialEquation.html) has the full derivation.

Comment: the book is in Hebrew.

Comment: @percusse I found this link as well but I cannot understand how to use this in an exam.

Comment: in the link I provided, equation number (8) to (11), is the variable substitution $e^z=x$ or $z=\ln x$. You can use this in an exam if you know how to solve the resulting second order diff. eq. with constant coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear that $$\frac{dx}{dt} = x.$$

Using the chain rule on $Y(x(t))$, this implies that

$$\frac{dY}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = x \frac{dy}{dx}.$$

You now derive once more with respect to $t$:

$$\begin{align}\frac{d^2Y}{dt^2} &= \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dy}{dx} + x \frac{d}{dt}\frac{dy(x(t))}{dx}.\\
&= x \frac{dy}{dx} + x \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \frac{dx}{dt}\\
&= \frac{dY}{dt} + x^2 y^{''}(x).
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are they doing but I know that for Euler differential equation we can make substitution $x=e^t$, and after that we can write following:

$x'_t=(e^t)'_t \Rightarrow \frac{dx}{dt}=e^t \Rightarrow dx=e^tdt$

Since we know that  $y'_x=\frac{dy}{dx}$ ,we can write:

$y'_x=\frac{dy}{e^tdt}=-e^t\frac{dy}{dt}=-e^ty'_t$

Similarly we can show that:

$y''_x=(y''_t-y'_t)e^{-2t}$

Now if you substitute these expressions into ODE you will get:

$ay''_t+(b-a)y'_t+cy=d(t)$, which can be solved if we first solve homogeneous equation:

$ay''_t+(b-a)y'_t+cy=0$